# Unable to launch spring application in tomcat on eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have imported one maven project in eclipse. But the problem is while I am trying to launch it on tomcat, spring initialisation is not taking place. I have added as follows:

[image]

Now while I am staring Tomcat server, only following log is coming, spring initialization is not happening:

```
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM 
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE: /Users/a0m0466/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM 
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/a0m0466/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.5.39
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/a0m0466/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: - Dcatalina.home=/Users/a0m0466/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.5.39
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/a0m0466/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/a0m0466/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.5.39/endorsed
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/a0m0466/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 511 ms
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.39
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 10, 2019 2:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 335 ms
```

Comment: Your server is running on 8080 as per log but don't see any Application being deployed. Log should show the project being deployed.

Comment: That's the issue, I don't understand how application is not getting deployed. I just added the project to tomcat and started it.